# Excel: Delete groups of rows that looks similar

Tags: excel

Using Find and using delete set of rows you can delete rows that contain certain content.

Is it possible to select and delete a group of rows that looks similar?

Take this excel file for instance. I want to delete all rows that are similar to 1576 to 1578, because there are many tables that has these values and I would like to get the "Mean" row right below "Dislike -B" row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Total` is in ColumnA, I think in Row2 of a spare column and copied down:

```
=OR(RIGHT(B2)="_",A1="Total",A2="Total")
```

will give you a flag to filter on to select rows for deletion.

Comment: Guess this is not required `RIGHT(B2)="_"`